# John 8:33 Why does Jesus not correct the Jews when they said they they were never slaves of anyone?

Tags: john

John 8

> <sup>**33**</sup>They answered him, “We are Abraham’s descendants and have never been slaves of anyone. How can you say that we shall be set free?”
>
> <sup>**34**</sup>Jesus replied, “Very truly I tell you, everyone who sins is a slave to sin. <sup>**35**</sup>Now a slave has no permanent place in the family, but a son belongs to it forever. <sup>**36**</sup>So if the Son sets you free, you will be free indeed. <sup>**37**</sup>I know that you are Abraham’s descendants. Yet you are looking for a way to kill me, because you have no room for my word. <sup>**38**</sup>I am telling you what I have seen in the Father’s presence, and you are doing what you have heard from your father.

Their ancestors were slaves in Egpyt. Why does Jesus not correct them?

Comment: I suppose that Jesus Christ's main concern was His Israelite countrymen's acceptance of His Messianic role as Lord & Saviour, and their repentance as sinners, therefore, their status as actual slaves to the Ancient Egyptians is relatively really a minor concern

Comment: I don't think they were thinking in those terms, since they were primarily speaking about themselves in Jerusalem(the translation may also be affecting the interpretation).

Comment: **(1).** *Their ancestors were slaves in Egpyt.* - Maybe, but they weren't. **(2).** *Why does Jesus not correct them?* - He does, though not in the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would sidetrack the point Jesus made that they were slaves to sin.  Jesus wasn't wanting to argue.  He was making a point.  Jesus was expecting their response.  With it Jesus captured their attention for making his point.

Comment: Not only that, but they seemed just as oblivious to Christ's sayings as His Own disciples. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Just remember to pay attention to the whole context or passage instead of getting lost by one sentence. The context makes it clear, they were referring to themselves in pride & privilege by saying we are Abraham's seed. They were not referring to the whole Israelites from history. Their own generation was not living in slavery despite being under the [Roman rule](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/roman-rule-63bce-313ce). They were later massacred and sold as slaves after the destruction of Jerusalem in 70 BCE.

> **[NASB John 8:31-44]**  <sup>31</sup>So Jesus was saying to those Jews who had believed Him, "If you continue in My word, [then] you are
> truly disciples of Mine; <sup>32</sup>and you will know the truth, and
> the truth will make you free." <sup>33</sup>They answered Him, "We are
> Abraham's descendants and have never yet been enslaved to anyone; how
> is it that You say, 'You will become free '?" <sup>34</sup>Jesus
> answered them, "Truly, truly, I say to you, everyone who commits sin
> is the slave of sin. <sup>35</sup>"The slave does not remain in the
> house forever; the son does remain forever. <sup>36</sup>"So if the
> Son makes you free, you will be free indeed. <sup>37</sup>"I know that
> you are Abraham's descendants; yet you seek to kill Me, because My
> word has no place in you. <sup>38</sup>"I speak the things which I
> have seen with [My] Father; therefore you also do the things which you
> heard from [your] father." <sup>39</sup>They answered and said to Him,
> "Abraham is our father." Jesus said to them, "If you are Abraham's
> children, do the deeds of Abraham. <sup>40</sup>"But as it is, you are
> seeking to kill Me, a man who has told you the truth, which I heard
> from God; this Abraham did not do. <sup>41</sup>"You are doing the
> deeds of your father." They said to Him, "We were not born of
> fornication; we have one Father: God." <sup>42</sup>Jesus said to
> them, "If God were your Father, you would love Me, for I proceeded
> forth and have come from God, for I have not even come on My own
> initiative, but He sent Me. <sup>43</sup>"Why do you not understand
> what I am saying? [It is] because you cannot hear My word.
> <sup>44</sup>"You are of [your] father the devil, and you want to do
> the desires of your father. He was a murderer from the beginning, and
> does not stand in the truth because there is no truth in him. Whenever
> he speaks a lie, he speaks from his own [nature], for he is a liar and
> the father of lies.

The corrupt Jews were very proud and arrogant on their religious heritage, being confident of themselves due to their religious ancestry, similarly to what many Christians might be today for their religious status in abandoning the true meaning and spirit of religion. This encounter with John the Baptist reveals a similar exchange.

> **[NASB Matt 3:7-9]**   <sup>7</sup>But when he saw many of the Pharisees and Sadducees coming for baptism, he said to them, "You
> brood of vipers, who warned you to flee from the wrath to come?
> <sup>8</sup>"Therefore bear fruit in keeping with repentance;
> <sup>9</sup>and do not suppose that you can say to yourselves, 'We
> have Abraham for our father'; for I say to you that from these stones
> God is able to raise up children to Abraham.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the Zadokite High Priests, **"Perushim" פְּרוּשִׁים‎ Pharisee sages descended from the sons of Matityahu HaKohen ben Yochanan מַתִּתְיָהוּ הַכֹּהֵן בֶּן יוֹחָנָן‎ whose Levitic line of Aharon passed down through יהוֹיָרִ֖יב Yehoyariv** "Jehoiarib" : 1 Maccabees 2:1 > [1 Chronicles 24]. * This 1st priestly division was assigned to יהוֹיָרִ֖יב Yehoyariv "Jehoiarib" : מִבְּנֵ֥י אֶלְעָזָ֖ר "from the Sons [of] Eleazar".

The Pharisees were descendants of Levi. **Levites were not slaves in 'Egypt', like the other tribes.**

Understand [Exodus 5:4] 'But the king of Mitsrayim said to them, "Why, Moshe and Aharon, [do you disturb the people from their work]? Go to your own labors." ' (וַיֹּ֤אמֶר אֲלֵהֶם֙ מֶ֣לֶךְ מִצְרַ֔יִם לָ֚מָּה משֶׁ֣ה וְאַֽהֲרֹ֔ן תַּפְרִ֥יעוּ אֶת־הָעָ֖ם מִמַּֽעֲשָׂ֑יו לְכ֖וּ לְסִבְלֹֽתֵיכֶֽם ) **If Moshe & Aharon were slaves in Egypt, why would Paroh פַּרְעֹ֔ה allow the two Levites to speak in his court?**

The Pharisees (descendants of Avraham **& Levi**) like Moshe & Aharon were not servants to Paroh in Mitsrayim. **This is why the Pharisees in John 8:33 spoke correctly in regards to their tribe in Egypt.**

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: What evidence do you have for these two assertions: (1) Levites were not enslaved, and (2) Pharisees were descendants were descendants of Levi?  Moses and Aaron were simply leaders - Moses had come from outside the country!

Comment: I subscribe to Dottard's Question & Criticism :) (It is easy to get caught in one's own riddles ...)

Comment: @Dottard - See update for validation of Perushim Sages' Levitic ancestry to Aharon through Eleazar's descendants.

Comment: Except that Saul/Paul said of himself: (Phil 3:5) circumcised on the eighth day, of the people of Israel, of the tribe of Benjamin, a Hebrew of Hebrews; in regard to the law, a Pharisee;  This contradicts your claim.

Comment: @Dottard - Thank you for helping distinguish actual scripture from the narrative of self-proclaimed “Hebrew of Hebrews”.